# YouTube channel and playlist ID prefixes

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I've noticed normal channel IDs have "*UC*" at the start while automatically generated ones have "*HC*". Normal playlists have "*PL*" but special ones, like uploaded or favourite videos, have "*UU*" and "*FL*", which however doesn't apply to autogenerated channels, they have "*LP*". That's what I've found so far. Is there any list of all these prefixes with their meaning?

Edit: Playlists based on a specific video begin with "*RD"*+the video ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested in this in 2024, the prefixes for automatic playlists of uploads are:

- UU - all public uploads (videos + shorts + live streams)
- UULF - all public videos
- UUMO - all member videos (alternative UUMF)
- UULV - all live streams
- UUSH - all shorts
- UULP - popular videos
- UUPV - popular live streams
- UUPS - popular shorts
- UUMV - member live streams
- UUMS - member shorts

Answer (score 1):

There is not a guideline and they may always change. I strongly suggest not to depend on them but the pure API methods.

Comment: I don't depend on them. I am just curious.

Comment: I noticed that the report CSV that one can download in a YouTube-CMS account lists the channelIds without the UC prefix. How do I work with that CSV Report without depending on the UC prefix?

Comment: @yankee Just add it?

Comment: @IllidanS4: If I add it, then I clearly depend on UC being correct.

Comment: @yankee YouTube would break quite a lot if they changed it. I think you are safe to depend on it, as it has been the same for quite a lot of time.