# How to tell the difference between a channel ID and YouTube username?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I need to accept a Youtube Channel ID OR Youtube username as input, and create a subscribe button for it.

Google has just changed the syntax, so that if it's a channel ID, you use this:

`<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw" data-layout="default" data-count="default"></div>`

But if it's a channel name you omit the `id` from the attribute. https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button

> You must specify a value for one of the following two attributes:
>   `data-channel` – The name of the channel associated with the button. Sample value: GoogleDevelopers.
>   `data-channelid` – The channel ID associated with the button. Sample value: UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw

What would be an easy way to tell if it's a channel ID or username?

All channels I have seen start with UC but that doesn't seem to be definitive: [YouTube channel and playlist ID prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795987/youtube-channel-and-playlist-id-prefixes)

Who knows why they did this but it's breaking many subscribe buttons as a result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if your input field starts with "UC_", "HC_", etc. for a channel per your link above. If not then it's a username.

Comment: That is what I'm doing for now, but Youtube doesn't publish that as a standard and it doesn't seem sure that all channels will begin with UC or HC. If I can't find any other answers then I'll accept this one however.

Comment: No, currently channels can start without _ symbol. So only UC and HC in the beginning (for example, UC6scIoqfqdu91_006ZLvJUg)